# How can I run my WEAR OS code if i dont have emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

My laptop can't enable Vr-x So I can't use android studio emulator.
So for run my code I use my mobile device like a emulator or some software like (Nox emulator),
Now i need to run a wear os apps so I dont find any emulator support wear os,
So can someone give me idea or Suggestion ?

Comment: What does VR-X have to do with Wear OS? VR-X is for VR apps. Wear OS is for smartwatches.

Comment: I mean 'VTx in BIOS' 
"virtual machine=disable" so i cant use android studio emulator,

Comment: I dont have BIOS password i try for a long time and i dont find any solution for recover bios password

Comment: It sounds like the easiest solution would be to just buy a Wear OS device. Or you can look for a device farm that offers Wear OS devices. The former will most likely be both cheaper and less time consuming in the long run.